# What is the workaround for using the @Observable and @Enviorment Macro as part of the Apple SwifftUI Tutorial?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

When using these macros, I receive the following errors:

@Observable Issue: Unknown attribute 'ObservableObject'

@Environment Issue: Cannot convert value of type 'ModelData.Type' to expected argument type 'KeyPath<EnvironmentValues, Value>', Generic parameter 'Value' could not be inferred

On the following page [link-to-page](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/handling-user-input) at Step 2 of Section 4, I am told to do the following :

[Step 2: Declare a new model type using the Observable() macro.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLL3j.png)

and then I am told to the following on Step 3:
[In LandmarkList, add an @Environment property wrapper to the view, and an environment(_:) modifier to the preview.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nLx3.png)

I have tried setting my class to adhere to the ObservableProtocol and setting my var landmarks to @Published as per another stack overflow post, but I do not know what I am doing nor what it meant. It seemed to remove the error message though for the @Observable issue.

Answer (score 0):

`@Published` does not work with `@Observable`.

`Observable` replaces `ObservableObject`

In iOS 17+ you should only use `ObservableObject`/ `Published` if you need `Combine` for some other reason.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-from-the-observable-object-protocol-to-the-observable-macro

That tutorial is tailored for iOS 17+ so if you are supporting anything less `Observable` won’t work. This is likely your issue.